# Strange Lines in Smoke Rendering with Cycles-

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, baking

When I render a smoke with this Domain Settings:

[image]

I get Some strange lines in the Render:

[image]
As you can see there are some straight lines in this image.
It's not like this image, for instance:

[image]

It's like in a worse quality, like there aren't enough subdivisions.

I'm having the same problem in other simulations, I tried to look online for help but I didn't find anything useful.

I tried also to download the file from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoRPa8OrwHs

And I rendered as It is on my PC with this settings:

- Render Engine: Cycles
- Device: GPU Compute.

But it turned out different from the one it's visible in the video, why?

Comment: Im not sure why you have those lines, did you make sure you baked it before rendering? also take a look at this video. He brings up a great point about not going over 96 divisions https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJa5-Dchy50 also I created a material to help control the smoke a little easier. Its not exactly what you want but it may help. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23859364/Pollution.zip

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=smoke+lines

Comment: @Ramos: your link refers to a full page of threads with zero answer to this issue, except one in a middle that is solved by Ctrl+A, but I'm not sure that's the same issue. What did you tried to say by that link? Thanks